# TileLayer displays in different order (Using React-Leaflet library)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to do a simple Web App using the library react-leaflet.

I have the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';

class LeafletMap extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      lat: 51.505,
      lng: -0.09,
      zoom: 13,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng];
    return (
      <Map center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
        <TileLayer
          url='http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        />
        <Marker position={position}>
          <Popup>
            <span>A pretty CSS3 popup. <br/> Easily customizable.</span>
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </Map>
    );
  }
}
export default LeafletMap;
```

However, The TileLayer is displaying in random order all the time. I've read a lot of code where It must work with `ComponentDidMount()` by `Reactjs`, but The renders that I've seen are totally different compared to the library.

Do you have any idea what can I do?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "displaying in a random order".  Could you be more specific?

Comment: @EricPalakovichCarr The final result is an image (OpenStreetMap TileLayer). It is displaying in random order as a puzzle without sequence.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm not sure what could be causing that problem.  Could you post a screenshot of the messed up map?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only reason It was not working is because we need to add the following code in `index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.2/dist/leaflet.css" />
<style type="text/css">
    .leaflet-container {
        height: 400px;
    }
</style>
```

That's all.

Comment: the problem is indeed that you manually need to include the css of leaftlet.